# Instagram API Change May 2016?

Tags: instagram-api

We are having problems with returning results from Instagram API for location (lat, lng) and hashtag searches. It only stopped working in the last couple of weeks.

Has Instagram changed API without warning?

PLEASE help us.

Does anyone also have a sample get call for hashtags?
The script is wtitten in Python.

Thank you

Coby

Comment: you should specify the change you have seen or the error you are facing because of any change in the API.

Answer (score 0):

Theres a new Instagram API update that happened in June 2016.

[refer dialogfeed doc link](https://www.dialogfeed.com/best-tips-for-instagram-api-update/)

I really wonder how they can increase traffic on insta by setting up stringint limitations. :-(

> The Doc stats - "This aims to limit third party inadequate uses of Instagram user contents and to increase trafic on Instagram."